# I believe this is a bug in clang related to a placement new-expression whose constructor throws

Tags: c++, clang, new-operator, c++14

The problem arises when a *new-expression* of the form `new(std::nothrow) C;` where `C` is a class name whose constructor throws. See the code below and the [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c0ed9a8ccd8c18c) using `g++`:

```
#include <iostream>

void* operator new(std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    void* p;
    p = malloc(size);
    std::cout << "operator new(std::nothrow)" << '\n';
    return p;
}

void operator delete(void* p, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    free(p);
    std::cout << "operator delete(std::nothrow)" << '\n';
    std::cout << p << '\n';
}

class T{};

class C {
    int i;
public:
    C(int i) : i{i} { std::cout << "C()" << '\n'; throw T{}; }
    ~C() { std::cout << "~C()" << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    C* c;
    try { c = new(std::nothrow) C(3); }
    catch (T&)
    {
        std::cout << "exception thrown in C(int) was caught" << '\n';
        std::cout << c << '\n';
    }
}
```

`g++` prints the following and it seems to be correct:

```
operator new(std::nothrow)
C()
operator delete(std::nothrow)
0x13f9c20
exception thrown in C(int) was caught
0
```

Whereas, if you use `clang`, you'll get the following output:

```
operator new(std::nothrow)
C()
exception thrown in C(int) was caught
0x7fffecdeed00
```

That is, it seems like `clang` is **not** invoking the `operator delete(void*, std::nothrow_t&)` defined in the program, and is calling instead, the operator  in the standard library.

The weird thing is that, by just deleting the expression `std::cout << p << '\n';` in the `operator delete(void*, std::nothrow_t&)`, defined in the code, `clangs` appears to execute correctly, printing:

```
operator new(std::nothrow)
C()
operator delete(std::nothrow)
exception thrown in C(int) was caught
0x7fffc0ffc000
```

**Edit**

In response to the comment by @T.C. below and to the others who say that the code above has undefined behavior, I present below another code that shows how the compiler should act, to correctly compile the snippet above, using the pseudo-code presented by @T.C. [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/l9ZOsATprVI/tXngvwIBCwAJ). See also this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bfb9e3617313a7d). An important point to note, is that this code **does not use** the *new-expression* `new(nothrow)`.

```
#include <iostream>

void * operator new(std::size_t n)
{
    void* p;
    try { p = malloc(n); }
    catch (std::bad_alloc&) { throw; }
    std::cout << "operator new" << '\n';
    return p;
}

void operator delete(void *p) noexcept
{
    free(p);
    std::cout << "operator delete" << '\n';
}

void* operator new(std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    void* p = malloc(size);
    std::cout << "operator new(std::nothrow)" << '\n';
    return p;
}

void operator delete(void* p, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    free(p);
    std::cout << "operator delete(std::nothrow)" << '\n';
    std::cout << p << '\n';
}

class T {};

class C {
    int i;
public:
    C(int i) : i{ i } { std::cout << "C()" << '\n'; throw T{}; }
    ~C() { std::cout << "~C()" << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    C *c;
    try
    {
        c = (C*)operator new(sizeof(C), std::nothrow);
        struct cleanup
        {
            void* p;
            bool active;
            ~cleanup() { if (active) operator delete(p, std::nothrow); }
            void dismiss() { active = false; }
        } guard = { (void*)c, true };
        new(c) C{1};
        guard.dismiss();
    }
    catch ( std::bad_alloc& ) { c = nullptr; }
    catch (T&)
    {
        std::cout << "exception thrown in C() was caught" << '\n';
        std::cout << c << '\n';
    }
}
```

`g++` prints the following for this code:

```
operator new(std::nothrow)
C()
operator delete(std::nothrow)
0x10c3c20
exception thrown in C() was caught
0x10c3c20
```

**Surprisingly, `clang` appears to act correctly with this code, that doesn't use the new-expression `new(nothrow)`, which clearly shows that `clang` has a bug while compiling this *new-expression*.**

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to read the uninitialized value `c`.

Comment: @KerrekSB If `c` is uninitialized, what would be the purpose of the placement `operator delete(void*, nothrow_t&)` ? See also this in §18.6.1.1/7 (N4140): `This nothrow version of operator new returns a pointer obtained as if acquired from the (possibly replaced) ordinary version`.

Comment: Your class constructor throws, so the assignment to `c` never happens.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't agree with this. The compiler introduces a call to `operator new()`, which is completely independent from the call to the constructor. So, if the constructor throws, an address of the allocated space will be returned by the *new-expression*. And in this case,  the replacement `operator delete()` is invoked to deallocate that space, as described in §18.6.1.1/7.

Comment: @KerrekSB Also, both clang and g++ would emit warnings if a variable is being used without being initialized.

Comment: Only if it can tell. The compiler gave it's best effort. There is a `c`. It was assigned with `new`. The fact that `c` experienced exceptional behaviour at runtime is not the compiler's problem. Gotta say it would be nice if the compiler did deep logic analysis to spot deliberate or accidental foot-shooting, but that's not what C++ does.

Comment: I'm not replicating your symptoms with clang (OS X latest).  If you initialize `c` (say to `nullptr`), do you still get the call to `delete` removed?  Are you using libc++?

Comment: @HowardHinnant Yes, I get exactly the same behavior in clang and g++, initializing `C *c = nullptr;` or without initialization.

Comment: @HowardHinnant `Are you using libc++?` I'm not very familiar with clang or g++. Could you tell me whether I'm using this, just by looking at the [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c0ed9a8ccd8c18c)?

Comment: There is no assignment to `c` here (The exception is thrown thus forcing the stack to unwind until it finds a catch block. The `new (std::nothrow)` does not stop the constructor of a class from throwing. As a result the value of `c` is indeterminate and reading it is `UB`.

Comment: For me, this code works as expected with GCC 6.0 on libstc++ and with Clang 3.7 on libc++.

Comment: @LokiAstari The stack is unwound, but at the time the exception is caught in `main()`, I believe `c` is still well defined.

Comment: @Belloc: Nope. The command that would assign `c` never completes. Now the result of `new` could have been put in the memory location used by `c` before calling the constructor or it could be in a register. The only guarantee you have is that **if the statement completes** then the value of `c` is set with the result of `new`

Comment: @LokiAstari See [this answer](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/l9ZOsATprVI/tXngvwIBCwAJ) by @T.C. to me in `c++ std-discusssion` and I believe you'll understand what I'm saying, although the example is about a different kind of a replacement `operator delete()`.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would cause this behavior is if the compiled std::lib did not mark `operator delete` as a weak symbol.  This would be a bug in the std::lib, or possibly a bug in its build process.

Comment: My code sample has nothing to do with what `c` will be in your code; it doesn't even assign an `A*` anywhere. In your code, `c` is uninitialized in the catch block - Loki and Kerrek are correct.

Comment: @T.C. Your code sample **has everything to do** with what I was saying up to this very moment. I firmly believe this is a bug in clang. See my **Edit** above.

Comment: Nope. Your code has a spurious assignment to `c` that is 1) not in my code and 2) not how it works. The assignment doesn't take place until the constructor call finishes.

Comment: @T.C. `2) not how it works. The assignment doesn't take place until the constructor call finishes` Based on what can you say this?

Comment: Think about what a new-expression does. It's an expression that attempts to create an object and returns a pointer to that object, which is then assigned to `c`.  It's an expression with fairly complicated semantics, but an expression nonetheless. If the evaluation doesn't complete (because an exception is thrown), nothing is returned, and nothing is assigned. Does `a = f();` write to `a` if `f()` throws an exception?

Comment: How is the value of `c` relevant to this behavior? The described problem is about the destructor call that should happen earlier.

Comment: @T.C. You've said it all: `It's an expression with fairly complicated semantics`, i.e., it's a different animal than a simple function call like `f()`. Also I didn't find anything in the Standard, that could corroborate what you said above: `the assignment doesn't take place until the constructor call finishes`, in the case of a *new-expression*.

Comment: No, the burden is on you to demonstrate that in `c = new A` the value computation of `new A` will produce a side effect on `c`. Because otherwise it's clear per [expr.ass] that the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of `new A`, which never finishes because it terminates by throwing an exception.

Comment: @T.C. [expr.ass] convinced me. The original code in my question has undefined behavior. I'm ready to accept this as an answer.

Comment: What exactly is undefined about this behavior? The value of `c` may be undefined, so expecting the address in `p` to be the same as the address in `c` would be a false assumption. However, this doesn't mean that the program behavior is undefined, since there is no attempt to read the memory behind `*c`

Comment: @grek40 The result of the expression `c = new(std::nothrow) C(3);` is undefined by [expr.ass], i.e., the lvalue `c` doesn't necessarily contain the address of the deallocated block. Then according to the Standard, anything can happen, even the usual `delete operator()` be invoked, instead of its placement overload, as clang does. Although, I would still consider the last part to be debatable, as the delete operator is invoked before the use of `c` in the catch clause. Maybe the experts could say something about this.

Comment: @T.C. If we delete the expression `std::cout << c << '\n';` in he catch clause in my original code, I believe the code will have a well-defined behavior. But even in this case, `clang` invokes the usual `operator delete()`, instead of its placement version. I think we could say that this is a bug in `clang`.

Comment: If the std::lib version of `operator delete` is not marked weak, it is a flip of the coin (at link time) which `operator delete` will get called.  If we knew what platform you were on, and/or what std::lib you were linking to, someone might be able to instruct you on how to inspect that binary for the linkage of `operator delete`.  While all of this talk about UB is true, it is also a red herring and waste of time as far as understanding this behavior goes.

Comment: @Belloc you cited 18.6.1.1/7 but I don't see how you meet this requirement in your code sample. Is the throwing `new` operator also implemented on `malloc` in your full sample? It might not obviously influence the result, but its *Required* after all...

Comment: I don't see this mentioned yet... before C++14, `std::cout << p << '\n';` caused UB (using an invalid pointer value). Since C++14 it's implementation-defined (with the possible case of it being defined to give a runtime fault). Before claiming that inclusion of this line causes clang to bug out, it would be good to check clang's documentation to see what it defines for the case of using an invalid pointer value.  Alternatively, avoid the issue by moving this line to before the call to `free(p)`.

Comment: The issue identified by @T.C. can be avoided by removing the code `c = ` and `std::cout << c << '\n'` from the original code.  Using coliru with clang++ -std=c++14, the "missing" operator delete is still missing in that case.

Comment: Is it possible that there would be a problem due to startup of `std::cout` needing to allocate some memory and trying to invoke these allocation functions?

Comment: @M.M `The issue identified by @T.C. can be avoided by removing the code c = and std::cout << c << '\n' from the original code. Using coliru with clang++ -std=c++14, the "missing" operator delete is still missing in that case.` I have already said something equivalent to this in my prior comment and my conclusion is that `clang` really has a bug while compiling the *new-expression* `new(nothrow)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my system, OS X 10.11.1, the std::lib-supplied `operator delete` is in /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib.  On Unix-like systems, this signature is made replaceable by giving it "weak linkage".  When the linker sees two identical signatures, and one of them has weak linkage, it will prefer the one that doesn't.

I can confirm that on my system, `operator delete(void*, std::nothrow_t const&)` has weak linkage with the following command:

```
$ nm -gm /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib |c++filt |grep nothrow_t
0000000000024406 (__TEXT,__text) weak external operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
00000000000243fc (__TEXT,__text) weak external operator delete(void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
00000000000243c0 (__TEXT,__text) weak external operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
000000000002437e (__TEXT,__text) weak external operator new(unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
```

Can you do the analogous analysis on your system and report the results?

**Update**

Thanks to T.C.'s instructions below on how to replicate the symptom, it now looks to me like this is a clang compiler code generation bug, introduced in 3.7, still present in tip-of-trunk, and only reproducible at -O2 (not -O1 or lower and not -O3).

I think a bug report is in order, and it should have good instructions on how to reproduce the bug (unless you want them to give this a low priority).

**PS**

And set `C *c = nullptr;` so that *they* don't waste time chasing irrelevant UB.

**2nd Update**

I still can not reproduce this locally with clang tip-of-trunk.  But I can see it on websites such as:

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5zIRyPJpq32LfU0t

I do not yet have an explanation for this discrepancy.  Perhaps my tip-of-trunk is more recent than theirs?  Perhaps they are not using libc++abi?

Comment: I have no familiarity with clang and g++. I just use their web compilers. So, unless you tell me exactly how to proceed, I will not be able to help you here. But as I said above, if we eliminate the use of the variable `c` in the catch clause in `main()` the cause for UB simply disappears, and clang continues to invoke the default `operator delete(nothrow)` instead of its replaceable version given in the code. And that is a bug, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Belloc you have to be more specific about your environment. Its no use tracking a bug that appears in *some* web-compiler frontend but not everywhere. Try [this web-frontend](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang) for a working clang version when you put in your example and the right flags. Its not even funny to read, that you opened this issue based on installations that are not accessible for further analysis.

Comment: @Belloc:  Show us how to replicate something that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think this is a linker issue. Inspecting [the generated assembly](http://goo.gl/ITfMvK) shows that no call to `operator delete(void *,  const nothrow_t&)` was emitted at all.

Comment: @HowardHinnant `Show us how to replicate something that doesn't work.`  See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/731f6897527be9c4). If you change -O2, to -O1 or -O3, the code works as expected.

Comment: @HowardHinnant `I think a bug report is in order, and it should have good instructions on how to reproduce the bug (unless you want them to give this a low priority).` I'll leave that to somebody with more experience and expertise than me. And I liked that: `And set C *c = nullptr; so that they don't waste time chasing irrelevant UB.` (+1). Thanks.